# Angular Tests always pass

Tags: angular, angular-test

I have the following service test which always passes regardless of what assertions i make. Can anyone please provide some pointers?

Cheers

KH

```
    describe('CourseDataService', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [CommonModule, TableModule, RouterTestingModule, 
            WidgetModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [CourseDataService, HttpClientWrapper]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

 it('should inject', () => {
    console.log('before inject');
    inject([CourseDataService], (courseDataService) => {
        console.log('inside inject never called');
        expect(courseDataService).toBeTruthy();
        expect(courseDataService).toBeFalsy();
        expect(courseDataService).toBeNull();
        expect(true).toBeFalsy();
    });

    console.log('after inject');
});
});
```

Comment: Why are you using async? If you need that, please use a callback function to your "it" call, and call that inside your async inject.

Comment: Thanks. I updated to be non async. Nothing seems to work. The test always passes - it never gets inside the injector

Comment: fit  = focused it

Comment: y i forgot that, that's why i removed the comment. sorry!